# Ext js 4.2.1 alert box doesn't look well

Tags: javascript, html, css, extjs

I have this code

```
    <html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="ext-all.js"></script>
<link href="ext-all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<script>
    Ext.onReady(function () {
      Ext.Msg.alert("Hello World","all set");
});
});
</script>
</html>
```

instead of alert box I see white box on top side and after box I see text Hello world,  and All set, whats problem ? js and css file are in correct place

Answer (score 0):

please see this page:
[example with run option](http://try.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.1/demos/Ext.Msg.alert.1/viewer.html)

vaersion of `extjs` (maybe) and `css` is important.